# What is the difference between _mm_set1_ps and _mm_set_ps1?

Tags: c, sse, intrinsics

Is there any difference between these functions? If not, why?

```
__m128 __mm_set1_ps(float a)
__m128 __mm_set_ps1(float a)
```

Both descriptions are the same on the [Intel Intrinsics Guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm_set) website.
Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**There is zero difference.  `_mm_set1_ps` is idiomatic, use it.**

e.g. clang's xmmintrin.h defines `set_ps1` in terms of `set1_ps`:

```
static __inline__ __m128 __DEFAULT_FN_ATTRS
_mm_set_ps1(float __w)
{
    return _mm_set1_ps(__w);
}
```

---

#### History guesswork

My guess is that Intel just hadn't settled on a naming scheme back in the early days of SSE1, and switched to `_mm_set1_`type going forward.  But if they'd already documented `_mm_set_ps1`, they couldn't take it back.

Note that there is no `_mm_set_epi321` or `_mm_set_ep81` (fortunately)!  Thus `_mm_set1_ps` is idiomatic and follows the same pattern as the other broadcast intrinsics, while `_mm_set_ps1` is unusual and will surprise human readers.  There is `_mm_set_pd1` and `_mm_load_pd1`, though, and presumably they were introduced at the same time (with SSE2).

I only know about it because I stumbled over it the other day while looking for an intrinsic that would do a strict-aliasing-safe broadcast load, like you could with `vpbroadcastd` in asm.  (There isn't a portable one that compiles efficiently everywhere; compiler support for intrinsics is a mixed bag of braindead pessimizations and missing intrinsics when you try to do anything complicated.  Maybe in a few more years `_mm_loadu_si32(void*)` to zero extend will at least be widely supported..)  /end off topic rant.